# How to change vector color in a resource from code behind

Tags: wpf, vector

How would I change the vector color from the code behind?  Code behind in this example doesn't work.

From the Resource Dictionary..

```
<VisualBrush x:Key="Alarm-Light">
    <VisualBrush.Visual>
        <Canvas>
            <Path  Data="M12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22M12,7L7,12H10V16H14V12H17L12,7Z" Fill="#424242" />
        </Canvas>
    </VisualBrush.Visual>
</VisualBrush>
```

From the Xaml..

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextConnect" Width="20">
<Rectangle x:Name="AlarmLight" Fill="{StaticResource Alarm-Light}" Height="16" Width="16" />
```

Code Behind...

```
 private void Connection_Check()
 {
        var brush = LocalSystem.Connected ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.GreenYellow) : new SolidColorBrush(Colors.DimGray);
        AlarmLight.Fill = brush;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
    <VisualBrush x:Key="Alarm-Light">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=AlarmFill}" Data="M12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22M12,7L7,12H10V16H14V12H17L12,7Z"  />
            </Canvas>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

With this code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        AlarmFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets AlarmFill Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public Brush AlarmFill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(AlarmFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlarmFillProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlarmFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AlarmFill", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

---

Or this one:

```
    <VisualBrush x:Key="Alarm-Light">
        <VisualBrush.Visual>
            <Canvas>
                <Path Fill="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=DataContext.AlarmFill}" Data="M12,22A10,10 0 0,1 2,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,2A10,10 0 0,1 22,12A10,10 0 0,1 12,22M12,7L7,12H10V16H14V12H17L12,7Z"  />
            </Canvas>
        </VisualBrush.Visual>
    </VisualBrush>
```

With this code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        AlarmFill = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or Sets AlarmFill Dependency Property
    /// </summary>
    public Brush AlarmFill
    {
        get { return (Brush)GetValue(AlarmFillProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AlarmFillProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AlarmFillProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("AlarmFill", typeof(Brush), typeof(MainWindow), new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

Comment: No. in none of these two approaches